# Handle XSS and Unicode characters in C#

Tags: c#, unicode, xss, handle

I have a C# code which handles Unicode characters. The below code also encodes XSS code.

```
String s = "<<SCRIPT>alert("Hack");//<</SCRIPT>";
var resultText = Microsoft.Security.Application.AntiXss.HtmlEncode(s);
string encodedValue = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(resultText, Encoding.UTF8).Replace("+", "")

txtResult.Text = encodedValue;// display in the text box in UI
```

But the above displays data in a different way.I want to display the text

```
<<SCRIPT>alert("Hack");//<</SCRIPT>
```

in the textbox( txtResult)

Can any one help me in achieving this.
Basically i am trying to handle XSS and Unicode characters.

Comment: Does that even compile? You need to escape those quotes.

Comment: basically its an example which i framed, but i am looking for solution to this

Comment: What is `txtResult`? The `Text` properties of some webforms controls take markup and others plain text. For a plain text control no escaping is needed at all. I'm not sure what the URL-escape-and-remove-pluses step is supposed to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

```
void Main()
{
    string _js = @"<<SCRIPT>alert(""Hack+"");//<</SCRIPT>";
    
    // Break it down into bytes
    byte[] _bytes = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_js);    
    
    // Use the single unicode character literal representation of the characters wanting to strip
    //      '+' = +, etc...
    byte[] _sanatizedBytes = _bytes.Where(b => b != '+').ToArray();
    
    // Dump the bytes back into a UTF8 string
    string sanitizedJavascript = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(_sanatizedBytes);
    
    string _safeJavascript = Microsoft.Security.Application.Encoder.HtmlEncode(sanitizedJavascript);
    
    string decode = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(_safeJavascript);
    
    var txtdecoded = new TextBox() { Text = decode};    
    
}
```

This is likely the most redundant way to go about it, since you're breaking it down, running your own sensitizations and then plugging it back in.

Personally I would just use `Microsoft.Security.Application.Sanitizer.GetSafeHtmlFragment(_js);` this strips out all blacklisted tags, such as script, and anything in between it, regardless of UTF8, ANSI, etc.